# Change the color of the controller when changing orientation from vertical to upside down

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

How can I change the color of a view controller with `self.view.backgroundColor = self.randomColor;` , 
when a change in orientation occurs from portrait to upside down portrait?

Method for random color:

```
-(UIColor *)randomColor
{
    CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0
    CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from white
    CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from black
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];

    return color;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "updown"? Do you mean ["upside down"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)?

Comment: "Upside Down Orientation"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
 -(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
       withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{

    //you can try somethign like
        if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown) {

    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

      }

}
```

> Notifies the container that the size of its view is about to change.

That method gets trigger whenever you rotate your device.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be the case that `UIViewController` had methods that one could override to detect orientation changes (such as [`willRotateToInteraceOrientation:duration:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:)).  All of these have been deprecated at this point, as Apple intends developers to not worry about orientation and think more about the traits and size of the container the `UIViewController` has to work with.

So the best practice at this point would probably be to implement [`viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:) and change your background color in this method.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];
}
```

Or in Swift:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    self.view.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
}
```